# How can I select a specific value via XSLT/XPATH and use that value for another tag?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am a beginner in XSLT and I would like to ask for some help with this.
Need to use XSLT 1.0 - here the task:

This is my simplified input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FILE>
    <Partner>
        <NR>10</NR>
        <SR>
            <VK>100</VK>
            <PF>
                <TYPE>WE</TYPE>
                <NR>2345</NR>
            </PF>
            <PF>
                <TYPE>RE</TYPE>
                <NR>666</NR>
            </PF>
            <PF>
                <TYPE>RG</TYPE>
                <NR>999</NR>
            </PF>
            <RESULT></RESULT>
            ...
        </SR>
        <SR>
            <VK>200</VK>
            <PF>
                <TYPE>WE</TYPE>
                <NR>97564</NR>
            </PF>
            <RESULT></RESULT>
        </SR>
    </Partner>
    <Partner>
        <NR>20</NR>
        <SR>...</SR>
    </Partner>
</FILE>
```

Target Output must look like this: 
(Tag RESULT must contain value if there is a `<PF>` node of type = "RG", otherwise empty)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FILE>
    <Partner>
        <NR>10</NR>
        <SR>
            <VK>100</VK>
            <PF>
                <TYPE>WE</TYPE>
                <NR>2345</NR>
            </PF>
            <PF>
                <TYPE>RE</TYPE>
                <NR>666</NR>
            </PF>
            <PF>
                <TYPE>RG</TYPE>
                <NR>999</NR>
            </PF>
            <RESULT>999</RESULT>
            ...
        </SR>
        <SR>
            <VK>200</VK>
            <PF>
                <TYPE>WE</TYPE>
                <NR>97564</NR>
            </PF>
            <RESULT></RESULT>
        </SR>
   </Partner>
   <Partner>
       <NR>20</NR>
       <SR>...</SR>
   </Partner>
</FILE>
```

Note:
I am updating an already existing working and productive xslt here, so I can not change something major here.
This is a snippet from the relevant coding:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="FILE">
        <FILE>
        <xsl:for-each select="./Partner">
            <Partner>
             ...

            <xsl:for-each select="./Partner/SR">
                ...

                <xsl:for-each select="./PF">
                    ...
                    <xsl:if test="(./PF/TYPE =RG)">
                        <RESULT><xsl:value-of select="./PF/NR"/></RESULT>
                    </xsl:if>     
                </xsl:for-each>


            </xsl:for-each>

            </Partner>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </FILE>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The test for type = RG is successful, but it copies over always the first number 2345 from type WE.

How can I access and copy over the specific value (999) from type RG?
The order and amount of PF entries is not fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the test for type = RG is successful? At the moment you do this

```
 <xsl:if test="(./PF/TYPE =RG)">
```

But this is within the context of an `<xsl:for-each select="PF">` meaning your if statement is looking for a `PF` element that is a child of the current `PF` element (and so will find nothing). Additionally, if is also looking for an element called `RG` to test for the equality, as opposed to a literal. I think it should be this.

```
<xsl:if test="TYPE = 'RG'">
```

As for the `xsl:value-of`, as you are already positioned on the "RG" element, the expression can be simplified to just `NR`. So your `xsl:if` then becomes like so:

```
<xsl:if test="TYPE = 'RG'">
    <RESULT><xsl:value-of select="NR"/></RESULT>
</xsl:if>
```

Having said that, it looks like your XSLT could benefit from using the XSLT [identity template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), especially if you are only changing the `RESULT` element.

Try this XSLT instead....

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SR/RESULT">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="../PF[TYPE='RG']/NR" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Many thanks! You directed me in the right direction.